# Realizar una operacion aritmetica en un archivo csv python

Tags: python

Buenas estuve intentando generar una lista de cada línea en un archivo csv para después "filtrar" la data del nro del contenido que son cajones de frutas y precio por cajon para calcular el costo total.

Este es el archivo csv

```
nombre,cajones,precio
Lima,100,32.2
Naranja,50,91.1
Caqui,150,103.44
Mandarina,200,51.23
Durazno,95,40.37
Mandarina,50,65.1
Naranja,100,70.44
```

Como mencione necesito que el programa abra el archivo, lea las líneas, y calcule el precio pagado por los cajones cargados en el archivo que se llama camion.csv. Para poder imprimirme este valor

```
Costo total 47671.15
```

Intente con este codigo aunque pude acceder calcular el costo de las naranjas pero no se como orientarme para acceder a los demas precios y cajones.

```
f = open('../Data/camion.csv', 'rt') #ubicacion del archivo
headers = next(f).split(',')
headers
['nombre', 'cajones', 'precio\n']
for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        print(row)
cajonesnaranja = float(row[1])
precionaranja = float(row[2])
costonaranja = cajonesnaranja * precionaranja
print(costonaranja)
```

Comment: Puedes usar pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una variable costo donde le iras sumando a cada línea el costo individual. Así en lugar de sólo calcular el de la ultima línea como esta en tu código, lo hará en cada una.

```
f = open('camion.csv', 'rt')
headers = next(f).split(',')

costo = 0
for line in f:
        row = line.split(',')
        costo += float(row[1]) * float(row[2])
print(costo)
```

Comment: Gracias capo sos un crack.